# Python - Word count not working on data extracted form a JSON

Tags: python, json

I have extracted some information from a JSON and save it in a variable, then, I strip some of the information and save it in a string which look like this:

```
BPnda
BPnda and O
BPnda
Cova
DR
DR
O
DR
Customer rep
DR
O
TIU reports and validations
Reports from CARE 
Cova
```

The goal is to count the amount of times a line repeats. I had to use replace() to remove the white spaces because it was not counting properly the lines, however, when I try to count them I still have not the results I want. This is what I am getting at the moment:

```
BPnda :  1
BPnda and O :  1
BPnda :  1
Cova :  1
DR :  1
DR :  1
O :  1
DR :  1
Customer rep :  1
DR :  1
O :  1
TIU reports and validations :  1
Reports from CARE  :  1
Cova :  1
```

This is what I am trying to get:

```
DR :  4
BPnda :  2
Cova :  2
O :  2
BPnda and O :  1
Customer rep :  1
TIU reports:  1
Reports :  1
```

This is the code I am using, I have use the word_count function in other programs and it works, however I am not sure why here is not working:

```
def word_count(doc):
    counts = dict()
    words = doc.split()

    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1
    return counts

issues_test=s_json[['issues'][0]]
description=""
for item in issues_test:
    description = (item['fields']["description"])
    source= dict()
    for item in description.split("\n"):
        if "Source of detection" in item:
            source = (item.strip("*Source of detection:*"))
            source = source.replace(" “,”_”)
            count=word_count(source)
            sorted_d = sorted(count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
            for key, value in sorted_d:
                print(key, ' : ', value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I you didn't share the whole JSON file, the only thing that I can see is that your code counts words, but your expected output counts the **lines and not the words.** If I change that in my code it works fine.

My code:

```
def word_count(doc):
    counts = dict()
    # words = doc.split()
    lines = doc.split('\n')

    for line in lines:
        if line in counts:
            counts[line] += 1
        else:
            counts[line] = 1
    return counts
INPUT= """BPnda
BPnda and O
BPnda
Cova
DR
DR
O
DR
Customer rep
DR
O
TIU reports and validations
Reports from CARE 
Cova"""

output = word_count(INPUT)
print(output)
```

with as output:

```
{
 'BPnda': 2,
 'BPnda and O': 1,
 'Cova': 2,
 'DR': 4,
 'O': 2,
 'Customer rep': 1,
 'TIU reports and validations': 1,
 'Reports from CARE ': 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and help me. However, this still do not work. The JSON I have is too long and it also has some information I cannot share.